# On MacOS, how can I turn off yellow highlighting and popup "Look up" windows when I e.g. try to select code from Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

At present, I am using a Linux VM on my Mac for certain purposes, because it is now very difficult to select and copy a segment of code from a Terminal window without some token being highlighted in yellow and a popup window with a definition etc. pops up, disrupting my effort to highlight code.

Under System Preferences, "look up" highlights Spotlight and Trackpad. Turning off Spotlight does not seem to have mitigated this behavior.

How can I copy and paste code from a Terminal window? I have a workaround for some of the issue in that I can View Page Source from Brave and select it there, but it would be really nice to have the ability to select and copy code from a Terminal window normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it here:

System Preferences > Trackpad > Turn off "Look up & data detectors"

Comment: Thank you!!!!  This has been driving me mad.

Comment: I googled this again after installing a new OS and found this post. I tried to upvote it before I realised it was me!